# Getting model values in biew (Asp.net MVC )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send my `Model` from controller to the `View`.

It goes well. However `View` fails to show it.

```
public class TestModel
{
  public cars {get; set;}
  List<Bike> bikes {get; set;}
}
```

How can I read Models values in the `View`?

I have tried this:

```
@model Data.ViewModel.TestModel
```

But I can't then use Feach() in my view

Comment: show foreach loop you tried

Comment: Also share the controller code.

Comment: The 1st 'property' makes no sense (and wont compile) and the 2nd is not public

Comment: Provide [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What the heck is `Feach()`? Oh, I guess you mean `foreach`?

Comment: Update your question with controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how you can iterate your model collection.

First in your controller method populate a collection to pass down to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TestModel test = new TestModel();
    List<Bike> bikes = new List<Bike>();
    Bike bike1 = new Bike
    {
        Name = "Yeti",
        type = "Mountain"
    };
    Bike bike2 = new Bike
    {
        Name = "Santa Cruz",
        type = "Mountain"
    };
    Bike bike3 = new Bike
    {
        Name = "Knolly",
        type = "Mountain"       
    };
    bikes.Add(bike1);
    bikes.Add(bike2);
    bikes.Add(bike3);
    test.Bikes = bikes;

    return View(test);
}
```

And here is a real simple example of the view:

```
@model ASPNETMVCTEST.Models.TestModel
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Bikes
            </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         @foreach (var bike in Model.Bikes)
         {
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     @bike.Name
                  </td>
              </tr>
         }
     </tbody>
</table>
```